# error when generating xlsx file in node.j

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

help with xlsx-tempalte
I am doing everything according to the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-template), but an error occurs when calling substitute method. From the library code it is not clear what the problem is. Can you tell me what could be the problem?
I can't send real examples on NDA. I don't want to start sewing under any of them, because I think I will have to wait too long for a possible answer.

> `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') -get (/app/node_modules/xlsx-template/lib/index. js:22:20) at /app/node_modules/xlsx-template/lib/index.js:875:91 at Array. forEach (<anonymous>) at Workbook. substituteTable (/app/node_modules/xlsx-template/lib/index. js:874: at /app/node_modules/xlsx-template/lib/index.js:245:53 at Array. forEach (<anonymous>) at /app/node_modules/xlsx-template/Lib/index.js:232:54`

I did everything according to the documentation. I expect the result to be a generated exel with inserted data

Comment: Which one version of xlsx-template package in package.json file?

Comment: "xlsx": "0.18.5",
    "xlsx-template": "1.4.3"

Comment: Please share your code to debug it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.